# How to create an anchor, add an 'onclick' function and convert to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a anchor like this:

```
windowcontent = addField("<a  href='#info' id='myid' onclick='createList(" + parts + ")'>Info</a>");
```

where parts is a complex object. Since like this it always throws me error I read that I should use `createElement` instead.
So I did like this:

```
var o = document.createElement('a');
o.setAttribute('href', 'info');
o.onclick = createList(parts);
var t = document.createTextNode('Informazioni aggiuntive');
o.appendChild(t);
windowcontent = addField(o.outerHTML);
```

but like this in `o.outerHTML` I don't have like `onclick=".."` so when I click on my link nothing happens.

How can I do it?

Comment: You have tagged this question with jQuery and jQuery would provide a simpler solution. Is jQuery an option for you?

Comment: yes it would be ok for me..

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind jQuery (and the OP says they don't) you could do something like this:

```
// Create an anchor element, using an optional set of properties
var $anchor = $("<a>", { href: '#info', 'class':'myclass', 'data-parts': parts, text: 'Info'});

// When added to the DOM results in <a href="#info" class="myclass" data-parts="test,anothertest">Info</a>
$(document).append($anchor);

// create a delegated click handler for the anchors
$(document).on('click', '.myclass', function(){
    // get the parts stored in the data- attribute
    var parts = $(this).data('parts');
    // create the parts
    createList(parts);
});
```

### Quick mockup:

https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/1ca3c4cp/

### Notes:

- I assumed you need multiple items and used a class instead of an ID as IDs must be unique on a page. Browsers use a fast-lookup dictionary for IDs and these only allow one element to be stored against each ID value.
- This example uses a delegated event, attached to a non-changing ancestor element of the added elements. In this case I used `document` as the default. Delegated events apply the selector at event time, so work on elements that did not exist when the event was registered.
- I only inject the required data as an attribute on the anchor for later retrieval. With loads of anchors this also results in smaller HTML than adding inline onclick event handlers.
- You should avoid using inline event handlers generally with jQuery. They bypass some of the extra event features in jQuery and separate the event registration from the event handler code (bad for maintenance).

Comment: This is a good answer, and yes it's annoying to receive an undeclared downvote. But anonymous voting is explicitly permitted (see discussions on _Meta_) so no-one is in a position to insist on it. I think very high rep users are just expected to weather the odd downvote - especially if their mean daily increment is ~80 or so! `:-)`

Comment: I've trimmed another couple of cases of voting commentary, I hope that's OK. If you don't agree please ping me, and I'll ask a question on _Meta_.

Comment: "try having every answer you post down voted because you upset somebody" - are you the target of serial downvoting? If so, report that to a moderator, so they can look into it. Normally that would be handled automatically by the automatic rollback scripts, but subtle cases of it may be missed.

Comment: Please do report it, since users involved in unfair voting practices may be doing it to other users who are not nearly so able to weather it. Of course, only report to mods if you believe you _are_ being targetted by one individual - given that you have a large number of answers I'd imagine you'd get a downvote every few days just naturally.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you're being targetted then, but given that your rep will increase naturally even on days you do not participate, I think the best advice would be to ignore it.

Comment: @halfer: until you commented today I was ignoring it. Please remove your comments and I will do the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
o.onclick = createList(parts);
```

invokes `createList`. Try using `Function.prototype.bind()` to reference `createList` instead of calling `createList` , set `this` to `o` , set parameters passed to `parts`

```
o.onclick = createList.bind(o, parts);
```